# Pattern for returning data from Angular AJAX calls

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

Take a look at this method returned in a factory:

```
fetchEmployeeList: function() {
    var q = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/Employee/')
         .success(q.resolve)
         .error(ajaxErrorHandler.handleError);

    return q.promise;
}
```

The author of this code says that this is the model we should use for returning data from HTTP endpoints. Basically, any time we need data from a service, we should use this pattern. The author is under the impression that this is preferred over returning $http.get()'s return value instead.

I don't understand the point of this code, though. I thought $http.get() *does* return a promise.

Can someone explain what this example snippet is doing or what they think the author might be trying to do?

Comment: is it from a book or a blog, can we have the whole context?

Comment: Sorry, this is an offshore worker who is on holiday at the moment. :(

Comment: Sorry, it's just that many blog posts tend to over simplify problems up to the point where the code to answer the non-problem looks overkill. Maybe your worker is paid by the number of lines he writes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the deferred [anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns), which practically warps a promise when not needed.

in your case returning a q.promise seems like an abuse since the HTTP object can return a promise itself.

I'd refactor the code to the following:

```
fetchEmployeeList: function() {
    return $http.get('/Employee/');
}
```

you can take a look to this [blog post](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/) for more reference as well,

don't be afraid to open a **discussion** with whoever is suggesting that approach.