# How can I resolve a promise once a CSV is done reading?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, promise

I'm using the 'fast-csv' module found here (https://www.npmjs.org/package/fast-csv), but I'm willing to change that. I tried promised-csv (https://www.npmjs.org/package/promised-csv) but I couldn't wrap my head around it. I'm also using q (https://www.npmjs.org/package/q).

This is part of a long chain of promised functions, so I'll only bother you with this one and the one immediately after.

```js
var csvRows = [];

var parseCSV = function(){
    var d = q.defer();
    csv
        .fromPath(school+'_export1.csv')
        .on('data', function(data){
            csvRows.push(data);
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            done = true;
            d.resolve();
        });                
    return d.promise;
}

var updateSchedule = function(){
    var d = q.defer();
    console.log(csvRows);
    // csvRows.forEach(function(row){
    //     console.log(row);
        // connection.query('INSERT INTO schedule SET section_id = "'+data[0]+'", student_id = "'+data[1]+'", course_number = "'+data[2]+'", period = "'+data[3]+'", teacher_id = "'+data[4]+'", school_id = "'+school_id+'"', function(err, rows){
        //     if(err){
        //         console.log(err);
        //         d.reject();
        //     }
        // });
    // });
    d.resolve();
    return d.promise;
}
```

When I console.log(csvRows) from the .on('data') method, it logs each row individually, as it should. If I then console.log(csvRows) from the .on('end') method, it logs the entire array at once. Perfect. I then tried to resolve the promise here, but when it moves to the next function and I try to console.log(csvRows) I get an empty array. So I get that the promise isn't actually resolving, but I'm not quite sure how to resolve it. I'd really appreciate your help!

EDIT: This is my promise chain:

```js
deleteRows()
  .then(function(){
      parseCSV();
  })
  .then(function(){
      updateSchedule();
  })
  .done();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need wait for the promise to get resolved and you need to pass the data in the promise,
try something like this:

```
 var parseCSV = function(){
        var d = q.defer();
        csv
            .fromPath(school+'_export1.csv')
            .on('data', function(data){
                csvRows.push(data);
            })
            .on('end', function(){
                d.resolve(csvRows);
            });                
        return d.promise;
    }

var updateSchedule = function(){
   parseCSV.then(function(rows){
   //TODO, your code here
   });
}
```

EDIT:

try to chain your promises like this:

```
deleteRows()
  .then(function(){
      return parseCSV();
  })
  .then(function(rows){
     //TODO, whatever you need to do with rows
     return updateSchedule(rows);
  })
  .done();
```

but I'd prefer something like this:

```
deleteRows()
  .then(function(){
       return parseCSV().then(function(rows){
           //Todo your code here
       });
  }).done();
```

be careful with promises and try not to abuse of them.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Sorry, I"m new to promises. Where does "done" come from? I just added my promise chain to my original post. What's the difference between calling the function before instead of within the next function?

Comment: I just copied pasted your own code, there's no relevance for it, I've deleted it

Comment: OH! Ha! I know where that came from now lol. Sorry about that. And thank you!

Comment: So I can't get passing a value in the promise to work. When I pass in "csvRows" and call .then(function(){parseCSV(csvRows) in my promise chain I still get an empty array.

Comment: it should be something like .then(function(rows){return parseCSV(rows)}, what does done contains? remember to do a resolve and pass the data with it  like d.resolve(csvRows);

Comment: So just to try to understand what happened, my promise chain is now saying to return the function once the promise is received instead of simply running it. Also you recommended nesting promises? It seems like I arbitrarily used csvRows to resolve parseCSV()'s promise. Could I pass any variable in there, and as long as I call it within the correct .then(function(){}) the promise will be resolved in the correct place? It seems like I'm really misunderstanding the basics of this.

Comment: well in every chain you are returning a promise, it could be in a state of resolved, not resolved and rejected, once you resolve a promise you can pass the data within the resolve itself that way you are going to be able to get it in the appropriate 'then' (which is the even that get fired when you resolve your promise), just be careful to don't over do promises you can get trapped into an antipattern

Comment: take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919251/pattern-for-returning-data-from-angular-ajax-calls/26919537#26919537

Comment: I think starting to get it... I kept trying to pass values from ".then" to ".then", if that makes sense. You're supposed to ".then" the function you want to pass the value from within the ".then" it's contained in.